# Applying textures to a vertex buffer object primitive

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, vbo

How do you apply textures to a vertex buffer object in Android?

**ANSWER:**

---

The code works fine, except it is missing a call to

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

This and  the call of

```
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

are both required for in order for vertex buffer object to draw texture.

---

**QUESTION:**

From what I know, first you must create a NIO Buffer:

```
ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texCoords.length * 4);
tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
FloatBuffer textureBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
textureBuffer.put(texCoords);
textureBuffer.position(0);
```

In this code sample, the array *texCoords* contains the 2-component (s, t) texture data.

After creating the NIO Buffer, you need to pass it to opengl and create Vertex Buffer Object:

```
int[] id = new int[1];//stores the generated ID.
gl11.glGenBuffers(1, id, 0);
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id[0]);
gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoords.length * 4, textureBuffer, GL11.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

So that takes care of all the initalization. Next we need to draw it, and we do so like this:

```
gl11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);//enable for textures
gl11.glActiveTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE0);
//lets pretend we created our texture elsewheres and we have an ID to represent it.
gl11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

//Now we bind the VBO and point to the buffer.
gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id[0])//the id generated earlier.
gl11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);//this points to the bound buffer

//Lets also pretend we have our Vertex and Index buffers specified.
//and they are bound/drawn correctly.
```

So even though this is what I would think would be needed in order for OpenGL to draw the texture, I have an error, and only a red triangle (without my modulated stone texture) renders.

Comment: I apologize. I can confirm that all the code I provided does work. I only missed one thing `gl11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D)`. I thought I was enabling by using `gl11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)`, but it appears that I need to call both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions for VBO's need to be called to enable textures.

gl.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);